# sql to get records between those dates only

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I have this

```
start_date   end_date   record_id
2012-10-05   2012-11-05   1 
2012-10-06   2012-12-05   2 
2012-10-05   2012-09-05   3 
2012-11-05   2012-11-30   4 
2012-09-05   2012-11-21   5 
2012-10-05   2012-11-22   6
```

if todays date is `2010-10-05` I want to select all the records that are within the bounds, i.e that started today or earlier and not have not reached the end_date yet

so in this case it would be

```
2012-10-05   2012-11-05   1 
2012-10-06   2012-12-05   2 
2012-09-05   2012-11-21   5  // doesnt't end till 2012-11-21
2012-09-05   2012-11-22   6  // doesnt't end till 2012-11-22
```

Comment: Also, you've tagged php here - why?  Do you need the php code to get this as well?  It sounds like you haven't even tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE start_date < SYSDATE()
AND  end_date  > SYSDATE()
```

Assuming your `start_date` and `end_date` are of `DATE` type, otherwise you'll need to convert to `DATE`